# Can I use the same Team Viewer Account on 2 devices and connect those together?

Tags: teamviewer, viewer

At my place of employment, my boss wishes to purchase the Team Viewer license for himself myself, being his employee. There is one plan that allows up to 3 devices to use Team Viewer, so my question is can my device and my boss's device use Team Viewer from the same account at the same time and connect to each other to work?

Comment: You should ask teamviewer but I xan see this being a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure if i understood your question correcetly.

Correct me if im wrong but, are you asking if deviceA can access deviceB without any teamviewerID/Pass if they are both under the same account?

If so, the answer would be yes.

As you can see in the image below, I have registered my homePC and work laptops to my account so that I can **access it without needing anyone present** infront of the target device. (This can be changed so that someone needs to confirm the connection from the target device)

[Screenshot of teamviewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXimN.png)

Edit: Also, multiple connections are possible as far as im aware.